# Can't choose date after month view change - fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, html, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I use the fullcalendar to indicate the days when a courier can be ordered. You can always choose one of the two days that are after today (not including Saturday and Sunday). If you change the month view, you won't select any day. I do not know why.

January (I can choose February 1)

[image]

After changing the view to the following month on February 1 - you cannot click

[image]

```
$("#receiveCalendar").fullCalendar({
locale: 'pl',
buttonText: {
  today: 'Dziś'
},
dayClick: function dayClick(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
  if ($(jsEvent.target).hasClass('fc-future')&&!$(jsEvent.target).hasClass('fc-sat')&&!$(jsEvent.target).hasClass('fc-sun')&&$(jsEvent.target).hasClass('enable')) {
    $('#receiveDateValue').val(calEvent.format('YYYY-MM-DD')).change();
    $(".fc-day, .fc-day-top").removeClass('selected');
    $(jsEvent.target).addClass('selected');
    $(".fc-day-top[data-date='" + $(jsEvent.target).data('date') + "']").addClass('selected');
  }
},
viewRender: function(view, element){
  console.log(view)
  console.log(element)
  let day1, day2;
  let todayDate = new Date($('.fc-today').data('date'));
  let todayDateObj = moment(todayDate).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
  if ($('.fc-today').hasClass('fc-thu')) {
    day1 = moment(todayDateObj).add(1, 'days');
    day2 = moment(todayDateObj).add(4, 'days');
  } else if($('.fc-today').hasClass('fc-fri')){
    day1 = moment(todayDateObj).add(3, 'days');
    day2 = moment(todayDateObj).add(4, 'days');
  } else if($('.fc-today').hasClass('fc-sat')){
    day1 = moment(todayDateObj).add(2, 'days');
    day2 = moment(todayDateObj).add(3, 'days');
  } else {
    day1 = moment(todayDateObj).add(1, 'days');
    day2 = moment(todayDateObj).add(2, 'days');
  }
  day1 = day1.format("YYYY-MM-DD")
  day2 = day2.format("YYYY-MM-DD");
  $('.fc-future[data-date="'+day1+'"], .fc-future[data-date="'+day2+'"]').addClass("enable");
},
eventRender: function(eventObj, $el) {
  $el.popover({
    content: eventObj.description,
    trigger: 'hover',
    placement: 'top',
    container: 'body'
  });
},
events: holidays
});
```

Comment: Ok i think i figured out why i can't pick a date after changing month view. There is no day with the "fc-Today" class in the new month view. this class is necessary to determine on which day the courier can be ordered.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem myself. As I wrote in the comments above, the problem was with the "fc-today" class. The new month view didn't include it. I wrote a few lines of code to solve this situation:

```
viewRender: function (view, element) {
//some of new variables
let day1, day2, secondDayOfNextMonth, formattedDate, diff;

// new block of code
const currentDay = new Date();
const startOfNextMonth = moment().add(1, 'M').startOf('month').format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
let firstDayOfNextMonth = moment(startOfNextMonth).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
let firstDayOfNextMonthName = moment(startOfNextMonth).format('ddd');

formattedDate = moment(currentDay).add(3, 'days').format("YYYY-MM-DD");
diff = moment(firstDayOfNextMonth).diff(moment(formattedDate), 'days');

if (!$('.fc-day').hasClass('fc-today') && (firstDayOfNextMonthName === 'Mon') && (diff >= 0 && diff <= 3)) {
    secondDayOfNextMonth = moment(firstDayOfNextMonth).add(1, 'days').format("YYYY-MM-DD");
    $('.fc-future[data-date="' + firstDayOfNextMonth + '"], .fc-future[data-date="' + secondDayOfNextMonth + '"]').addClass("enable");
}
// end new block of code
```

};